# Power BI Direct Query : Couldn't load the data for this visual

Tags: powerbi

I am learning power BI , now i have connected the query in direct mode , in power BI desktop i can connect and can see the data . But, after publishing report the data is not visible.

I am getting Couldn't load the data for this visual error message.

```
Activity ID: f1fc0347-000a-4595-a075-8e02e6xxxa0c
Request ID: ff9b350a-60c8-d33b-0498-0axxxce86f9b1
Correlation ID: 8438fd94-3d45-e13b-a316-xxx84c70d6a
Time: Tue Jan 11 2022 19:18:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Service version: 23.0.17407.45
Client version: 2112.4.09339-train
Cluster URI: https://abc-north-dd-l-q-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to an on premise database, you need a Gateway. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem